# Discord Py Bot users Status

Tags: python, arrays, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        await client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f".help auf {len(client.guilds)} Servers", 
                                                type=ActivityType.playing))
```

I want to show the status of the total amount of members. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Axiumin's answer is correct but that requires you to have the intent.members enabled.

An example of enabling it can be done like so

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        await client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f".help auf {len(client.users)} Users", type=ActivityType.playing))
```

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. Since you are developing your bot you might want to enable Presence intent as well to save you time later.

However, if your bot is not allowed it(if your bot is in 100+ servers and discord rejected it's request) you can get around this by doing:

```py
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        total_members = 0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            total_members += guild.member_count
        await client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f".help auf {total_members} members", type=ActivityType.playing))
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This counts the total amount of users in all servers the bot is in, not how many are using the bot at that time. In order to do that, you'd have to use a counter and increment it each time a new user uses the bot, which I won't go into unless that's what you're trying to do.

This should work: `len(client.users)`. You'd use it in your `change_presence` code like this:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=Activity(name=f".help auf {len(client.users)} Users", type=ActivityType.playing))
```

Comment: Oh I find out Thnx